# Building a Certificate Authority architecture

Tags: java, keystore, pki, csr

I am trying to build a network involving multiple clients and a single server, both written in Java.  I am trying to find a way to automatically generate a CSR on the client side that can be sent to the server for a signed certificate.  I have been able to generate a public/private keypair in Java but cannot figure out how to generate a CSR.  Maybe I am looking at doing this the wrong way!  Please help!

Comment: Is your question about "certificate authority architecture", or is it "how do I create a CSR"?

Comment: A little of both.  I am assuiming a CA architecture that requires a CSR to be generated and sent to a server that will then generate a certificate that is sent back to the client.  I am new to CA's so if there was a different way of handling certificate generation from a server other than CSR's I don't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the end of this article.  It explains how to use the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org) libraries to generate both a certificate and a PKCS#10 CSR.  This should be all you need to get this working.

http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation

Answer (score 1):

You might want take a look at the [Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) to help you generate a CSR. They have [documentation](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation) on how to go about it. Here's an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/CreatingaCertificationRequest.htm) that requires Bouncy Castle. I came across [KeyUtils.java](http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/DictorVoiceIdent/VoiceIdent/src/security/KeyUtils.java) that has a `writeCertReq()` method, however it depends on some internal `sun.security` imports instead (so it'll be limited to the Oracle/Sun JVM). I'm actually not aware of a way to do it with the standard JCE.