# How to create a Certificate sign request using native Java

Tags: java, pki, csr

Is there a way to create a pkcs10 CSR using native java library?

Hello there, i am looking for a way to generate a PKCS10 CSR within an java application.
I prefer native java librarys. Absolutely obsolet are commandline tools. I know it is possible by using BouncyCastle, but currently i am looking for a alternative way to do that.
The library itself should be free to use for commertial belongings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into answer number 2 on [Building a Certificate Authority architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520215/building-a-certificate-authority-architecture?rq=1). There seems to be no way to do what you want with JSSE directly.